# How to run PowerShell scripts from C#

Tags: c#, powershell, registry, impersonation

I am trying to run a PowerShell script with C#, but I don't have any success. Here is my function:

```
private void ExecutePowerShellCommand(string scriptfile)
{
    RunspaceConfiguration runspaceConfiguration = RunspaceConfiguration.Create();

    Runspace runspace = RunspaceFactory.CreateRunspace(runspaceConfiguration);
    runspace.Open();

    RunspaceInvoke scriptInvoker = new RunspaceInvoke();
    scriptInvoker.Invoke("Set-ExecutionPolicy Unrestricted");

    Pipeline pipeline = runspace.CreatePipeline();

    //Here's how you add a new script with arguments
    Command myCommand = new Command(scriptfile);
    //CommandParameter testParam = new CommandParameter("key", "value");
    //myCommand.Parameters.Add(testParam);

    pipeline.Commands.Add(myCommand);

    // Execute PowerShell script
    pipeline.Invoke();
}
```

This is the error I get:

> Access to the registry key 'HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\PowerShell\1\ShellIds\Microsoft.PowerShell' is denied.

How can I solve this issue? I have seen ideas for impersonation, but I didn't seem to find any good examples to impersonate. I would like to run this script as an administrator.

I have made the following declarations:

```
[DllImport("advapi32.dll")]
private static extern bool LogonUser(string lpszUsername, string lpszDomain, string lpszPassword, int dwLogonType, int dwLogonProvider, ref IntPtr phToken);
[DllImport("kernel32.dll")]
private static extern bool CloseHandle(IntPtr handle);

public delegate void IncognitoDelegate(params object[] args);
```

I have created the following function for impersonation:

```
public static void Impersonate(IncognitoDelegate incognitoDelegate, params object[] args)
{
    System.IntPtr token = new IntPtr();
    WindowsIdentity wi;
    if (LogonUser("myusername", "", "mypassword", 8, 0, ref token))
    {
        wi = new WindowsIdentity(token);
        WindowsImpersonationContext wic = wi.Impersonate();

        incognitoDelegate(args);

        wic.Undo();
    }
    CloseHandle(token);
}
```

I have created a function which is used as a delegate:

```
private static void GIncognito(params object[] args)
{
    RunspaceInvoke scriptInvoker = new RunspaceInvoke();
    scriptInvoker.Invoke("Set-ExecutionPolicy Unrestricted");
}
```

And I have modified my method:

```
private void ExecutePowerShellCommand(string scriptfile)
{
    RunspaceConfiguration runspaceConfiguration = RunspaceConfiguration.Create();

    Runspace runspace = RunspaceFactory.CreateRunspace(runspaceConfiguration);
    runspace.Open();

    Impersonate(new Util.IncognitoDelegate(GIncognito));
    //RunspaceInvoke scriptInvoker = new RunspaceInvoke();
    //scriptInvoker.Invoke("Set-ExecutionPolicy Unrestricted");

    Pipeline pipeline = runspace.CreatePipeline();

    //Here's how you add a new script with arguments
    Command myCommand = new Command(scriptfile);
    //CommandParameter testParam = new CommandParameter("key", "value");
    //myCommand.Parameters.Add(testParam);

    pipeline.Commands.Add(myCommand);

    // Execute PowerShell script
    pipeline.Invoke();
}
```

The result was...

... the very sam error, telling me I can't access registry keys.

Comment: re: can't access registry keys-- You will have to either use an account that can modify registry keys or use a technique that does involve changing the execution policy from inside a running powershell instance.

Comment: @Lajos: impersonation is a lot of overkill for this... all you need to do is change the scope that the `Set-ExecutionPolicy` uses... see my answer below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The default `Set-ExecutionPolicy` command attempts to set the machine-wide value. You only want to change the setting within the scope of your C# application, so you should add the `-Scope Process` option to the command.

Using `Get-Help Set-ExecutionPolicy -detailed` reveals this information:

> NOTE: To change the execution policy for the default (LocalMachine) scope, start Windows PowerShell with the "Run as administrator" option.

... and it also describes the `-Scope` option.

This has the advantage of ***only*** impacting the execution policy for scripts run from your C# application, and it doesn't unnecessarily change the execution policy for the default PowerShell behavior. (So it's a lot safer, especially if you can make guarantees about the validity of the scripts your application runs.)

Answer (score 2):

Here is method b, that doesn't require elevated rights or 
*Registry modification rights*.

Using `Process.Start` launch this and add the relevant initial `-command` or `-file` args.

> %SystemRoot%\system32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\powershell.exe
>   -ExecutionPolicy bypass

Here is another technique, http://dmitrysotnikov.wordpress.com/2008/06/27/powershell-script-in-a-bat-file/

That relies on executing by encoding it first and passing int through the `-EncodedCommand` arg of powershell.exe, which appears to bypass execution policy.

Comment: I'm trying to run a git command and if I do it this way it asks for username and password. The problem is that I would like to make this fully automatic. If user name or password is needed, then human work is needed for each run. Can I make this fully automatic? Thanks.

Comment: git asks for a username password or windows? What's in your scriptfile?

Comment: git is out of my range of experience. I'm guessing you are getting prompted by git for credentials, maybe this will help: http://superuser.com/questions/338511/how-do-i-disable-password-prompts-when-doing-git-push-pull

Comment: I have edited my question. I have tried to implement an impersonate method. I don't know what is wrong, but something is certainly not right.

Answer (score 0):

You could try something like the following

```
using ( new Impersonator( "Username", "DomainName", "Password" ) )
{
    using (RunspaceInvoke invoker = new RunspaceInvoke())
    {
        invoker.Invoke("Set-ExecutionPolicy Unrestricted");
    }
}
```

Here is a link you can look at to get an idea as an example, [Class For Impersonating a User](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/10090/A-small-C-Class-for-impersonating-a-User).

Comment: Thank you for your post. To do this I need to use the Impersonator class, but I have no clue where can I find it or how can I implement it. I don't find a download link, only a link pointing to another page where an impersonator is described, but that can't be downloaded either, only the function shared there. Should I register to the site to be able to download these?

Comment: Looks like this code: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9909784/c-sharp-impersonator

Comment: Check out the link that Matthew Martin has posted as well I hope this information helps in getting started here is the link I posted as well in case it did not work from my initial post http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/10090/A-small-C-Class-for-impersonating-a-User

Comment: Ok, now I have the following error: Requested registry access is not allowed.

Comment: do you have the proper permissions / rights to run a powershell script..?

Comment: @DJ KRAZE, your link worked and I've registered to the web-site to be able to download the demo project. I have pasted the impersonator class which is the same as in the class linked by MatthewMartin, but I get an error, namely: Requested registry access is not allowed.

Comment: I posted a separate answer. I have the same issue on my work machine were I don't have admin rights, there are about 3 techniques for executing scripts w/o admin rights.

Comment: Yes, I have, but I can't seem to be able to do that from C#.

Comment: Also, I'm not sure I know what should be passed as 'domain' for a windows 7 user. Maybe localhost?

Comment: I have edited my question. I have tried to implement an impersonate method. I don't know what is wrong, but something is certainly not right.